# Почему phpstorm не видит шаблоны twig?

Tags: twig

Почему phpstorm не видит шаблоны twig и почему не работает автокомплит? Symfony плагин установлен. Версия шторма 2016.3.2. В контроллере в рендере отображается missing template, хотя по факту все работает.

Comment: А плагин "Twig support" установлен?

Comment: Да, установлен.